# How to solve this boundary value problem (2 coupled odes) with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I am solving a boundary value problem which is consisted of two odes.

Mathematica prompts that `SolveDelayed -> True` should be considered. However, the problem can not be solved even if this option was used.

I have read [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134921/how-to-solve-two-point-boundary-value-problem-bratu-type-equation?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43469/initial-and-boundary-value-errors?rq=1), but none of them helps.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Below is my code.

```
g = 15/10000;
Ri = 38/1000;
Ro = Ri + g;
m = 1/1000;
ηpos = 1/10;
τy = 2;
ϵ = 0.1;
λ = 1;
dpdz = 10^3;

η = τy/(Sqrt[u'[r]^2] + 10^-10) (1 - Exp[-m Sqrt[u'[r]^2]]) + ηpos;
τzz = τrz[r]^2 (2 λ)/η;
ode = {τrz[r] == η/(1 + (ϵ λ/η) τzz) u'[r], 1/r D[r τrz[r], r]== dpdz, 
       u[Ri] == 0, u[Ro] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[ode, {u, τrz}, {r, Ri, Ro}]
```

Comment: I have removed your commented code, since you should endeavor to only include code relevant to the problem at hand (and since it's commented, it's likely irrelevant).  Feel free to roll back those changes if you feel like they're important, though.

Comment: Thanks, it looks really better now. :)

Comment: Why do you say this is a **simple** boundary value problem?

Comment: Thanks for your attention. By 'simple', I mean that the physical problem behind the two odes is really common, and only two odes are loosely coupled. Sorry for this misleading word and I think I'd better to delete the word 'simple' in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

Solve it as an initial value problem, and then use a shooting method. The following formulation

```
g = 15/10000;
Ri = 38/1000;
Ro = Ri + g;
m = 1/1000;
ηpos = 1/10;
τy = 2;
ϵ = 1/10;
λ = 1;
dpdz = 10^3;

η = τy/(u'[r] + 10^-10) (1 - Exp[-m u'[r]]) +ηpos;
τzz = τrz[r]^2 (2 λ)/η;
ode = {τrz[r] == η/(1 + (ϵ λ/η) τzz) u'[r], 1/r D[r τrz[r], r] == dpdz, 
       u[Ri] == 0, τrz[Ri] == -0.75};
sol = NDSolve[ode, {u, τrz}, {r, Ri, Ro}, Method->{"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];
Plot[Evaluate[u[r] /. sol], {r, Ri, Ro}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}]
```

Practically solves the boundary issue. Use then the shooting method.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the valuable hint and it took me some time to understand what you mean, and finally I solved the problem according to your great hint. This is the first time that I realized the relationship between ic and bc problems :)

Answer (score 2):

You can regard the `trz` separetly.

First I rationalize all parameters and rewrite equation for simple testing later.

```
ode = {0 == -τrz[
  r] + η/(1 + (ϵ λ/η) τzz) u'[r], 
  1/r D[r τrz[r], r] == dpdz, u[Ri] == 0, u[Ro] == 0}
```

Since `trz` does not depend on `u`, treat it separatly.

```
dsol = DSolve[τrz[r]/r + Derivative[1][τrz][r] == 
          1000, τrz, r]

{*  {{τrz -> Function[{r}, 500 r + C[1]/r]}    *}
```

Insert the result and apply a starting condition instead of boundary condition, since `NDSolve` can not find an explicit equation for `u'[r]` and therefore switches to differential-algbraic equation.

```
ode2 = Join[Most[ode] /. First@dsol /. C[1] -> c, {u'[Ri] == aa}]
```

Omitt the `trz` part

```
ode3 = ode2[[{1, 3, 4}]]
```

Find a solution for the `c` parameter in dependance of `aa` with a little trick, since `Solve` does not find a solution for undefined `aa`.

```
cc2[aa_] = 
   c /. First@
 Solve[ode3[[1]] /. r -> Ri /. u'[Ri] -> -Pi, c, Reals] /. 
      Pi -> -aa;
```

Since shooting method did not work with Version 8.0, I guessed a value for `aa`. Find the exact `aa` with `FindRoot`.

```
ndsol = NDSolve[ode3 /. c -> cc2[aa] /. aa -> -88.1, u, {r, Ri, Ro}]
```

The solution satisfies ode.

```
u[Ri] /. ndsol
u[Ro] /. ndsol
Plot[u[r] /. ndsol, {r, Ri, Ro}, 
    Epilog -> {Red, Point[{Ro, u[Ro] /. First@ndsol}]}]
```

[image]

and the error (would be lower with aa found by `FindRoot`)

```
Plot[Evaluate[
   ode3[[1, 2]] /. c -> cc2[aa] /. aa -> -88.1 /. First@ndsol], {r, Ri,
    Ro}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: I really like your semi-analytical way to attack the problem, and it is very useful to my problem (which is larger than the mini problem in this post). I am sorry, I cannot check both answers :)

Comment: Thanks. No problem.